# Forum module for Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Are there any good Forum modules?

Comment: Removed the "JavaScript" tag... as Zend is a php framework and has nothing to do with JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is nothing like an **ready to use** "forum" Module for the Zend Framework. Further i think there is *no* complete Module ready to Download somewhere.

I would use the well known players in forum business like:

[PHPBB](http://www.phpbb.com/) or [SimpleMachines](http://www.simplemachines.org/)

And than try to integrate it , into your application. PHP is PHP :-)